# How to make Javascript image Slideshow change images slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm currently working on a slideshow that changes *Images*, *Title* and *Description* all at the same time with their `Array` number.
The slideshow works *BUT*, what I'm trying to accomplish is a **slow transition** to the **next/previous** Image (... title & description) when the "`Next`" and "`Previous`" buttons are clicked.
This can be done with either `javascript` or `jquery`. 
Any help or suggestions would be glady appreciated. Thank you.
Here is the `HTML`:

```
    <div class="featured">
        <div class="infofeat">
            <div class="infocont">
                <h1>FEATURED</h1>
                    <div id="feat_title">
                        First Title
                    </div>
                    <div id="description">
                        First Description
                    </div>
                <div id="controllers">
                    <a  id="_previous"href="#" onclick="return change_image(-1)" > Previous </a>
                    <a  id="_next"href="javascript:change_image(1)" > Next </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="picfeat">
            <img src="images/designs/tempfeatured.jpg" name="slideshow" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the slideshow `Javascript`:

```
var Image = new Array("images/designs/tempfeatured.jpg", "../images/designs/feat2.jpg", "../images/designs/feat3.jpg");
var Description = new Array ("First description", "Second Description", "Third Description");
var Title = new Array("First Title", "Second Title", "Third Title")
var Image_Number = 0;
var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;

function change_image(num){

    Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

    if (Image_Number > Image_Length){

        Image_Number = 0;

    }
    if (Image_Number < 0){

        Image_Number = Image_Length;

    }


    document.slideshow.src= Image[Image_Number];
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = Description[Image_Number];
    document.getElementById("feat_title").innerHTML = Title[Image_Number];
    return false;
}
```

You can test it out on JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2tgv2jw1/) . Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using a slideshow library?  If so, which one?

Comment: No, I got the script from a youtube video and I optomized it to my liking (Placed the title change and description to change with image).

Answer (score 0):

Each time a new picture is loaded, place it behind the original picture in a secondary image with the same location:

```
    <div class="picfeat">
        <img src="images/designs/tempfeatured.jpg" name="slideshow" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5" />
        <img src="images/designs/feat2.jpg" name="slideshow" style="position: relative; z-index: -5" />
    </div>
```

Then fade the first image with jQuery:

```
$('.picfeat:first-child').fadeOut(2000); // really slow
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid adding more images in HTML and just add a line of javascript to make a slow transition to change_image function whenever the next or previous buttons are clicked?

Comment: I believe that in order for a true fade to work, there must be two images, one fading and one being faded to. This is not avoidable I don't think. You could transition to black and then to the next picture as an alternative, this would not require two pictures.

Comment: How about something in javascript like: if click on `#_next` make a `setTimeout` on the function `change_image(num)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with css3, look this page and tell me if it was helpful: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is a very nice tutorial but I can't do any of those because I have a next and previous button working. I will definitly use this on my next project but for now, I need a solution using javascript or jquery. Thank you.